# MySQL Get row from joined table only if 1 such type exists

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, having

Trying to get my head around a maybe really simple query. It concerns two tables that I'm joining, but need to filter its result based on user selection in the web interface.

Table 'reports':

| report_id (PK, int) | report_name (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | report 1 |
| 2 | report 2 |
| 3 | report 3 |

Table 'policies':

| policy_id (int) | policy_report_id (FK, int) | policy_type (int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |

The user can specify (filter) if it only wants records that only contain policy type 1, type 2 or both.

Examples:

- User wants reports that only have `policies.policy_type` of **1**. Expected: `reports.report_id` is **2**.
- User wants reports that only have `policies.policy_type` of **2**. Expected: `reports.report_id` is **3**.
- User wants reports that only have `policies.policy_type` of **1** *and* **2**. Expected: `reports.report_id` is **1**.

A simple `WHERE` clause obviously doesn't work as it will return `reports.report_id`'s **1** *and* **2** if I would do `WHERE policies.policy_type = 1 AND policies.policy_type != 2`. Something along the lines of doing a `WHERE` clause on `GROUP_CONCAT` would help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more? You got my head twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT policy_report_id
FROM policies
GROUP BY policy_report_id
HAVING SUM(policy_type <> 1) = 0; -- no other than policy_type = 1
```

or:

```
HAVING SUM(policy_type <> 2) = 0; -- no other than policy_type = 2
```

If you want both policies 1 and 2 and no other policy:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND SUM(policy_type NOT IN (1, 2)) = 0;
```

The above query can be joined to `reports` to get the details of each report:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reports r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT policy_report_id
    FROM policies
    GROUP BY policy_report_id
    HAVING SUM(policy_type <> 1) = 0
) p ON p.policy_report_id = r.report_id
```

I assume that the combination of `policy_report_id` and `policy_type` in `policies` is unique and `policy_type` is not nullable.

Comment: Great work there!

Comment: Excellent. This provides the results I was expecting / looking for. Much appreciated, especially in such a short time-frame.